# Frightened + clumsy

Tags: conditions, pathfinder-2e, fear

Is there any benefit of inflicting [clumsy](https://2e.aonprd.com/Conditions.aspx?ID=3) 1 on an enemy that is already [frightened](https://2e.aonprd.com/Conditions.aspx?ID=19) 1?
(assuming the durations are the same)

(note to answerers: both clumsy and frightened inflict status penalties, and since everything that clumsy penalizes frighten also penalizes, adding clumsy to a frightened creature doesn't do much innately, as penalties of the same type do not stack - "[Like bonuses of the same type, you take only the worst all of various penalties of a given type](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=315).").

Comment: It may be good to explain why these conditions don't stack meaningfully: One is a strict subset of the other in terms of what is affected *and* they apply the same type of penalty (status) so they cannot stack additively

Comment: Anyone who can answer the question will know that, but feel free to add it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

#### There are reasons to apply both the Frightened and Clumsy conditions

The [Flamboyant Cruelty](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=2161) feat:

> You love to kick your enemies when they're down, and you look fabulous when you do. When you make a melee weapon Strike against a foe that has at least two of the following conditions, you gain a circumstance bonus to your damage roll equal to the number of these conditions the foe has. The qualifying conditions are *clumsy, drained, enfeebled, frightened, sickened,* and *stupefied*. If you hit such a foe, you gain a +1 circumstance bonus to skill checks to Tumble Through and to perform your style's panache-granting actions until the end of your turn.

Another theoretical option is if you have the ability to increase the value or extend the duration of the Clumsy condition (I haven't found any efficient ways to do this: Trying to critically fail with [Treat Condition](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=2029) is very much not efficient)

Perhaps not the most important benefit, but if an enemy is both clumsy 1 and frightened 1 it's going to be a lot harder for them to cure both instead of just frightened. Clumsy is usually a bit more difficult to cure; for example, [Mercy](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=225) allows you to counteract a fear effect, but you'll also need [Invigorating Mercy](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=1675) to counteract the clumsy condition. But even with both of those feats, you could only cure one or the other, so it'll be more difficult to remove all those penalties.

---

This post is a community wiki post. Feel free to add more examples to it.